# To get last 5 dates from curent dates for each Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

HI Can you help me with query for the below out put. I need the Last 5 Active days for each name and each date.

Input

```
Name date          Active
==== ====         ========
N1   07-30-2018      Y
N1   07-31-2018      N
N1   08-01-2018      Y
N1   08-02-2018      Y
```

Output

```
Name date       date2        Active
==== ========== =======      ======
N1   07-30-2018 07-25-2018    Y
N1   07-30-2018 07-26-2018    Y
N1   07-30-2018 07-28-2018    Y
N1   07-30-2018 07-29-2018    Y
N1   07-30-2018 07-30-2018    Y
N1   08-01-2018 07-27-2018    Y
N1   08-01-2018 07-28-2018    Y
N1   08-01-2018 07-29-2018    Y
N1   08-01-2018 07-30-2018    Y 
N1   08-01-2018 08-01-2018    Y
N1   08-02-2018 07-28-2018    Y
N1   08-02-2018 07-29-2018    Y
N1   08-02-2018 07-30-2018    Y
N1   08-02-2018 08-01-2018    Y
N1   08-02-2018 08-02-2018    Y
```

I am using below query to get this output can you please correct it

```
DECLARE @windowStart DATETIME SET @windowStart = '2016-08-01 00:00:00' 
DECLARE @windowEnd DATETIME SET @windowEnd = '2016-09-01 23:00:00'; 

Select a.Wellname,cast(a.timestamp as date) as date1,b.timestamp    --,date2 = dateadd(DAY,-N,timestamp) 
From  TableA --where cast(timestamp as date)>=@windowStart and cast(timestamp as date)<= @windowEnd 
Cross Join (
    Select * 
    from (
        Select distinct m.wellname, cast(m.[timestamp] as date) as timestamp ,Rank() Over ( partition by  m.wellname order by timestamp desc) as Rank 
        from TableA m  
        where m.updown<>'D'  and cast(m.[timestamp] as date) <= (Select cast(T.timestamp as date) from dbo.odr_nd_well_data T where cast(T.timestamp as date)=cast(a.timestamp as date)) and m.wellname in ('WN1','WN2')
        group by m.wellname,m.timestamp
    ) a where a.rank<=5
) B
 --on a.wellname=b.wellname 
where a.wellname='WN1' and cast(a.timestamp as date)>=@windowStart and cast(a.timestamp as date)<= @windowEnd
Order by a.wellname,a.date1,cast(b.timestamp as date)
```

Comment: What makes a date active?

Comment: @Richard I need the last 5 active days for each day and each name and i dont need the dates which are inactive in last 5 days. The 5dates are active dates it can be any last5 dates.

Comment: The input does not have any data for 7/25 through 7/29, but you include that in the output. Are you wanting to generate these dates, or is there more input data we can't see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a `CROSS JOIN` with an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,date2 = dateadd(DAY,-N,date)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Join (Select Top 5 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1) B
 Order By name,date,dateadd(DAY,-N,date)
```

**Returns**

```
Name    date        date2
N1      2018-08-01  2018-07-27
N1      2018-08-01  2018-07-28
N1      2018-08-01  2018-07-29
N1      2018-08-01  2018-07-30
N1      2018-08-01  2018-07-31
N1      2018-08-02  2018-07-28
N1      2018-08-02  2018-07-29
N1      2018-08-02  2018-07-30
N1      2018-08-02  2018-07-31
N1      2018-08-02  2018-08-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Saw your second post was closed.  Take a peek at

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select A.Name
          ,A.Date
          ,date2 = dateadd(DAY,-N,A.date)
          ,A.Active
          ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By A.Name,A.Date Order by dateadd(DAY,-N,A.date) desc)
     From  YourTable A
     Cross Join (Select Top 10 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1) B
     Left  Join (Select * from YourTable Where Active='N') C on A.Name=C.Name and dateadd(DAY,-N,A.date)=C.date 
     Where A.Active='Y' 
       and C.Name is null
)
Select Name
      ,Date
      ,Date2
      ,Active 
 From  cte
 Where RN <=5
 Order by Name,Date,Date2
```

**Returns**

```
Name    Date        Date2       Active
N1      2018-07-30  2018-07-26  Y       -- I think you had a typo in the desired results
N1      2018-07-30  2018-07-27  Y
N1      2018-07-30  2018-07-28  Y
N1      2018-07-30  2018-07-29  Y
N1      2018-07-30  2018-07-30  Y
N1      2018-08-01  2018-07-27  Y
N1      2018-08-01  2018-07-28  Y
N1      2018-08-01  2018-07-29  Y
N1      2018-08-01  2018-07-30  Y
N1      2018-08-01  2018-08-01  Y
N1      2018-08-02  2018-07-28  Y
N1      2018-08-02  2018-07-29  Y
N1      2018-08-02  2018-07-30  Y
N1      2018-08-02  2018-08-01  Y
N1      2018-08-02  2018-08-02  Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the simplified example in the other question. This is alternative, and arguably simpler, way to achieve the results:

```
select t1.name, t1.date, t2.date date2, t1.active
from  (
    select distinct name, date from [table] where active = 'Y'
)  t1
cross apply (
     select top 5 date 
     from [table] 
     where active = 'Y' and name = t1.name and date <= t1.date
     order by date desc
) t2
order by name, date, date2
```

What is not clear to me here is how to handle the dates between 7/25 and 7/29. These dates appear in the example output, but nowhere in the input. Do you want to generate these dates based on a number or calendar table (where there's an assumption they would have been active), is there more input data that was not shared, or did you want less output? This answer is written assuming there is more input that was not shared.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, You can also use 'procedural approach' as the following code :

```
declare @tbPrevDates TABLE(
    [name] char (3)
    ,[date] smalldatetime
    ,[date2] smalldatetime
)

declare @count int = -5

WHILE @count<>0
BEGIN
    INSERT @tbPrevDates SELECT [name], [date], DateAdd(d, @count, [date]) FROM YourTable
    SET @count=@Count+1
END 

SELECT * from @tbPrevDates 
ORDER BY
[name],[date],[date2]
```

However, John Cappelletti's answer is much more compact and advanced specific to SQL SERVER, my answer is somewhat 'generic' ...

Comment: Hi Noldy thank you for replying me back. i need to include the code in a procedure already existed.